# Why this java regex returning false?

Tags: java, regex

My intention is to locate all the "tokens" and quoted strings with a String::split() method:

```
(("[\w\s]*")|(\w*))*
```

Input text:

```
this  "a test" abd "and more"
```

It always returns false.

Also, how do I "quote" it so I can use it in the source code?

Comment: In Java you don't need double colon to call static functions :: xD

Comment: whats the shorthand to remind people that split is from String then? String#split ?

Comment: `String.split` returns `String[]`, so I'm not sure how it's returning false. Can you show the code and expected output with actual output?

Comment: [Since using # is mandatory for Javadoc](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/304403/264794), I'd say that yes, # is typically used. (I also use it myself)

Comment: 'how to "quote" it' do you mean using escape characters? You would need `((\"[\\w\\s]*\")|(\\w*))*` I believe some IDEs do this automatically when pasting (i.e. IntelliJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.split` splits using the matches as the separators, i.e. it returns everything that **doesn't** match. If you want to return what you're matching, you should use [`Matcher.find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

Also, `\\w*` matches a length 0 string, which you probably want to avoid. Use `+` to match 1-or-more.

You also have some unnecessary brackets and the outer `*` should not be there - the rest of the regex already matches all characters in a single token and multiple tokens should presumably be matched across multiple invocations of the regex matching (so saying "any number of these" doesn't make sense).

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"[\\w\\s]*\"|\\w+").matcher("this  \"a test\" abd \"and more\"");
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

The above prints:

```
this
"a test"
abd
"and more"
```

To remove the quotes, you can update the regex to use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which would check if the `"`'s are there, but won't actually match them:

```
"(?<=\")\\w[\\w\\s]*(?=\")|\\w+"
```

---

To understand how to escape things, you need to keep the different layers in mind. First there's Java itself, where having a `"` would start or end a string, so that needs to be escaped with a `\` if you want the `"` character to appear in a string. Then there's the regex code, which expects `\w` and `\s`, but Java doesn't allow `\` without it being escaped, so that's `\\w` and `\\s`.

Comment: Thanks for a beautiful, complete, working, and instructive answer :)